# Why must we specify the modules to be used in the gwt.xml files via the inherits tag?

Tags: java, gwt

Why must we specify the modules to be used in  the gwt.xml files via the inherits tag? Isn't it enough to just import classes and the gwt  compiler will just infere what the other dependencies to be included are?

Answer (score 1):

`gwt.xml` files contain many things that cannot be inferred from the code:

- `<source>` tells which classes are expected to work in client code; the rules can be complex and you can have several `gwt.xml` files in the same package with different rules (overlapping or not). Actually, I'm working on modularizing `gwt-user` and it required a lot of those *partitionning* (e.g. so that you can use the `Timer` or `Window` classes without importing the whole widget set)
- `<super-source>` tells GWT where it can find client-side specific implementations of classes. This is used to provide the emulation of the Java runtime, among other things (yes, the emulation of the Java runtime is (almost) entirely swappable if you think you have a better implementation of it)
- `<replace-with>` and `<generate-with>` configures [deferred binding](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html) which is used extensively in `gwt-user` (at a very low level to pick the fastest algorithm for `StringBuilder` depending on the browser, or a use `requestAnimationFrame` in browsers that support it, of workaround browser discrepancies, per browser; etc.)

And this is only a fraction of it.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  It is better to explicitly define what GWT modules you want to have loaded.  For example, If you have a dependency that has a .gwt.xml file in it and you only want to use the classes for server side things.  If that .gwt.xml file in the jar was auto-loaded, then any entry points specified in that file would be loaded.  This may not be what you want, and could cause unnecessary overhead in loading your gwt module.

Comment: "If you have a dependency that has a .gwt.xml file in it and you only want to use the classes for server side things" -exactly, so why wouldn't it be enough to just import the server side classes into my own code.  Why does not the gwt compiler adopt this strategy  and instead asks for users to also set inherits tags. Why isn't my strategy an option?

Comment: Did you read the rest of the response?  Any .gwt.xml files that are found in that jar would be auto loaded, which may not be what you want.